# How to do update with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE without using temporary table

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm using the below query to update the fields in my table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$_file'
REPLACE INTO TABLE test_db.productsinfo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\,'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'  
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(\`products_id\`, 
 \`products_source\`, 
 \`quantity\`, 
 \`cost\
)
```

But,`REPLACE` deletes the entire row and put's a new one ,which is not exactly the kind of update I require.
Unfortunately I cant use a temporary table due to speed issues.
Is there anyway to achieve the function of `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

If you need to do real-time updates to a table in a database, then SQL has this nifty statement, called `UPDATE`.  In all seriousness, you should do the update *explicitly* and not pass the values through a file, if speed is the primary concern.

Your application has already taken the time hit of putting the data into a file and (presumably) waiting for the writes to the file to be completed.  Additional time to load the data into a table for the `update` is just part of the process of "creating the file".

There may be ways to speed the update.  For instance, after loading into a temporary file, create an index on `toupdate(product_id)`.  That should speed a query of the form:

```
update products p join
       toupdate
       on p.product_id = toupdate.product_id
    . . .
```